# Capture click event of button in child component

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am using reactive forms and I have

1. parent component--- user click on name of file
2. Child component--- it pops out in bootstrap model.
   Now in this popup, there is a button and want to capture that using

Parent Component

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <app-resource-create #dCTRLED ></app-resource-create>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the full code of the child component

```
 ngOnInit(){
this.myform.controls['btn'].valueChanges.subscribe(test=>{
if(test){
this.isChecked=true;
}else{
this.isChecked=false;
 }
 });
}
```

**Problem** here is that this **.valueChanges** is not captureing the checkbox click.

What I want is whenever the checkbox is clicked then I want to show/hide the table row in the popup.